# Alter table with COMPACT STORAGE

Tags: cassandra, cql3, pycassa

I had issues with reading a table from pycassa created with CQL3.

So followed this post 
[Reading Cassandra 1.2 table with pycassa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185291/reading-cassandra-1-2-table-with-pycassa)

Now trying to alter my table

`ALTER TABLE tweets with COMPACT STORAGE ;`

But getting an error.

> Bad Request: line 1:32 missing '=' at 'STORAGE'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant alter the underlying storage model. You'll have to re-create the table and add the `WITH COMPACT STORAGE` parameter.

On a side note, why not use the newer [cassandra python](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver) driver that supports cql3.