# No module named cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm new to both Cassandra and Python.

I've downloaded and installed Cassandra as described in this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-cassandra-and-run-a-single-node-cluster-on-a-ubuntu-vps).

So, I have it in my PATH and I have also added it to my PYTHONPATH (not sure if I need this).

When I run test.py which contains:

```
import sys
print sys.path

from cassandra import cluster
```

It prints out PATH which contains

> /Users/[username]/Downloads/apache-cassandra-1.0.9/bin

which is where my cassandra bin directory is located. Is there something else I'm supposed to do?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want as a result. Also your version is rather old.

Comment: I clarified that it gives me a "no module named cassandra" error with that test.py file and I'm trying to get rid of it

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should remove `/Users/[username]/Downloads/apache-cassandra-1.0.9/bin` from `PYTHONPATH`. It's not the place for it.

`cassandra` package isn't there anymore. You'll have to use other library.

I'd suggest you look at this SO question [best Cassandra library/wrapper for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430417/best-cassandra-library-wrapper-for-python)

> The Cassandra project has been recommending that new projects use CQL
>   for a few versions now

Comment: pip also doesn't seem to be finding cassandra. When I try using pip, I get "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement cassandra" and "No distributions at all found for cassandra". To clarify, did you mean that I could use pip install as long as I have cassandra in my PATH?